# Есть всё(,) что нужно

Tags: запятые

Можете сказать, как правильно?

`У нас есть всё что нужно.`

`У нас есть всё, что нужно.`

Comment: нужна зпт - второе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устойчивое сочетание или сложноподчиненное предложение (разное акцентирование).

**Опять в магазин**

(1) — *У нас есть **всё что нУжно**, зачем в магазин-то ехать?*

(2) — *У нас есть **всЁ, что нужно**. — Может, что-нибудь ненужное купим?*